# how to replace a value with a parameter stored in a file

Tags: loadrunner

i want to replace the following values which appear small in size with a parameter.
i have created a file already.
just want to now how to replace them.

> ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*BICOASTALTPL   *01*006906614C
>   *170208*0924*U*00401*`000004263`*0*P*~^ GS*PR*BICOASTALTPL*006906614C*20170208*0924*4263*X*004010^ 
>   ST*855*4263^ BAK*06*AC*`004787022`*20170208^ DTM*002*20170215^
>   N1*BT*AmerisourceBergen^ N1*ST*ABC DC MANSFIELD*11*RA0290724^
>   N1*SU*BI-COASTAL/PGN*1*078397428^ PO1*1*60*EA*40*ND*4258260023^
>   ACK*IA*60*EA****ND*4258260023^ PO1*2*24*EA*16**ND*4293770810^ 
>   ACK*IA*24*EA****ND*4293770810^ SE*11*4263^ GE*1*4263^ IEA*1*000004263^

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parameter substitution and the parameter as a file type.
You can read more in [this article.](http://motevich.blogspot.co.il/2007/08/using-parameters-in-loadrunner-vugen.html) 
Please keep in mind that if you are using several parameters which are from the same file, you will need to **correlate** between them using the "**Same line as <*param*>**" option, so all parameters in the same file point each other on the same row.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your script > Go to parameters.
Click Add a new parameter and choose parameter type = file.
Point to the file that you created, making sure that the file has a header line with the parameter name (let's call it "param1").

So the file should look like this:

```
Param1
000000002121
00000003343
000003213213
```

Choose "param1" in the parameter name under the file preview.
Also, choose which way your load test will get each value (unique, sequential, random etc.).

Close the parameters window and return to the script.

Next, 
In your script code, replace the value `000004263` with `{param1}`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, insist that your managers send you to training & include a full time mentor for your professional development if they are going to ask you to use any performance testing tool.  These are the tactical nuclear devices of the software industry and should never be used without training.

Your question is covered in the classroom training material on parameterization.  It is covered in the included LoadRunner tutorial on parameterization.  It is covered in the online documentation on parameterization.  It is covered in the tool online help on parameterization.

You have clearly been prevented from taking advantage of any of these four options or you would not have would up here on Stackoverflow.